# Dynamically add rows for spring form using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Could someone please help me with the following?
I use spring for my project and i have a jsp page that has a table in which the first row is loaded from a controller. The table has also an "Add row" button with which the user can add multiple rows to add more records before the submission of the form.
What happens is that I use AutopopulatingList so in the submission each row to be handled as a seperate object in the controller.
My problem is with the add button. I use JQuery to add dynamically rows. But clone option is not suitable (i think correct me if i am wrong) cause I can not handle the index of the list. I used the following but nothing works.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Addcolsinviews Add</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {

$("#addStudentButton").click(function() {

          $('#dataTable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#dataTable tbody>tr:last');     
          return false;

});
});
</script>

    </head>
<body>
    <%@include file="header.jsp" %>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <%@include file="tableslist.jsp" %>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="subtitle">ADDCOLSINVIEWS ADD</div>   

  <form:form method="POST" name="addcolsForm" id="addcolsForm" commandName="addcolsinviewsadd">
        <table id="dataTable"> 
            <thead>
                    <tr margin-top="10px">
                        <th>Target View</th>
                        <th>Target Column</th>
                        <th>Source View</th>
                        <th>Source Column</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr  id="rowToClone">                           
                     <td>
                            <spring:bind path="addcolsinviewsadd.addcolsinviews[0].targetview">
                                <form:input path="${status.expression}"/>                              
                            </spring:bind></td>            
                        <td>
                            <spring:bind path="addcolsinviewsadd.addcolsinviews[0].targetcol">
                                <form:input path="${status.expression}"/>
                            </spring:bind></td>    
                        <td>
                            <spring:bind path="addcolsinviewsadd.addcolsinviews[0].sourceview">
                                <form:input path="${status.expression}"/>
                            </spring:bind></td>
                        <td>
                            <spring:bind path="addcolsinviewsadd.addcolsinviews[0].sourcecol">
                                <form:input path="${status.expression}"/>
                            </spring:bind></td>  
                        <td><input type="button" id="addStudentButton" value="Add"/></td>

                    </tr>                        
             </tbody>
          </table>                 
           <input id="actionbtn" type="submit" value="Process">            
 </form:form>   
             </div>
      </div>                   
</body>
</html>
```

and the second trial was the part of the jquery as follows:

```
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">      

    $(document).ready(function() {

var incrementVar = 0;
$("#addStudentButton").click(function() {
    incrementVar++;
            var appendTxt = "<tr>";
        appendTxt = appendTxt +                     
             "<td><spring\:bind path=\"addcolsinviewsadd.addcolsinviews[" + incrementVar + "].targetview\">";
            appendTxt = appendTxt + 
             "<form\:input path=\"${status.expression}\"/>";
            appendTxt = appendTxt +
             "</spring\:bind></td>";                 

            appendTxt = appendTxt +                     
             "<td><spring\:bind path=\"addcolsinviewsadd.addcolsinviews[" + incrementVar + "].targetcol\">";
            appendTxt = appendTxt + 
             "<form\:input path=\"${status.expression}\"/>";
            appendTxt = appendTxt +
             "</spring\:bind></td>";  

            appendTxt = appendTxt +                     
             "<td><spring\:bind path=\"addcolsinviewsadd.addcolsinviews[" + incrementVar + "].sourceview\">";
            appendTxt = appendTxt + 
             "<form\:input path=\"${status.expression}\"/>";
            appendTxt = appendTxt +
             "</spring\:bind></td>";

           appendTxt = appendTxt +                     
             "<td><spring\:bind path=\"addcolsinviewsadd.addcolsinviews[" + incrementVar + "].sourcecol\">";
            appendTxt = appendTxt + 
             "<form\:input path=\"${status.expression}\"/>";
            appendTxt = appendTxt +
             "</spring\:bind></td></tr>";
   alert(appendTxt);   

$("#dataTable tr:last").after(appendTxt);

</script>
```

The problem with the above is that no row added at all. The page seems to try to add a row but it is too small.. and i get no errors. In the alert of appendTxt the ${status.expression} does not exist. The path is null. I this that this is the problem.
Does anybody know if the syntax is ok or if I can write this somehow else??

I dont know what to do and I have already search a lot.. Please I would appreciate your help.

Comment: why do you use 2 click handlers for one element?

Comment: what do you mean 2 click handlers? I have only the addStudentButton for the add button..

Comment: I can see one of them clones and one of them appends the data, this can make a conflict between the two.

Comment: Oh no ... I tried 2 different things. One that clones and it does not work because the index of addcolsinviewsadd.addcolsinviews[0].targetview can not change or I dont know how and the second trial does not even create a new row...

Comment: Could someone plz tell me if the form that I have in the code above with the spring binding is able to be cloned ? Cause I think (after a lot of effort and search) that the binding necessary for the new rows is not able to be cloned like this... Should I use Ajax??  I would greatly appreciate someone's help. thank you...

Answer (score 4):

There is a very helpful article here... [jquery clone form fields and increment id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018132/jquery-clone-form-fields-and-increment-id)

So the answer is to use clone() and use a regular expression to increment your index.  Details and an example are given at above link. Appending a Spring form element will not work as the append is happening browser side and spring form elements are compiled server side.  Browsers know nothing of Spring elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the HTML source of a page once it has rendered, you'll notice `<\form:input>` changes to just `<\input>` due to processing on the server side before it reaches the browser.

Therefore, using jQuery to insert `form:input` will not work; you will need to input it in its HTML rending form. Look at the already rendered `<\tr>` 's and copy its content in the same format. (i.e don't use `path=`, use `value=`, `name=`, etc).