# JQuery .append() adds invisible elements, visible text

Tags: jquery, append, invisible, spring-form

I am using JQuery to add form elements when a button is pressed.  The problem is that I can't get the elements to render.  Just the text "-- start typing name --" is rendered.  When I right click and inspect element I see all the jquery rendered elements.  There is no styling to keep the newly added elements from being view-able.  No console errors.

This is a snippet from my .js file it should insert form elements

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var orgPosition = 0;
    $("#addOrgButton").click(function() {
        orgPosition++;

        $('#orgs').append('<br><div class="field_container"><form:label path="org_id"><spring:message code="label.org_id" /></form:label><form:select id="org_id" class="selectorg" path="jobOrgs[' + orgPosition + '].org_id"><form:option value="0">-- Start typing name --</form:option><form:options items="${organizationsList}" itemLabel="organization" itemValue="org_id" /></form:select></div>');
    });
```

from my jsp...

```
<form:form id="formid" method="post" action="addJob.html" commandName="jobModel">
    <div id="orgs">
        <div class="field_container">
            <form:label path="full_name">
                <spring:message code="label.jobFullName" />
            </form:label>
            <form:input class="input" path="full_name" />
            <form:errors path="full_name" cssClass="job_error" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="field_container">
            <form:label path="abbreviation">
                <spring:message code="label.abbreviation" />
            </form:label>
            <form:input path="abbreviation" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="field_container">
            <form:label path="org_id">
                <spring:message code="label.org_id" />
            </form:label>
            <spring:bind path="jobOrgs[0].org_id">
                <form:select id="org_id" class="selectorg" path="${status.expression}">
                    <form:option value="0">-- Start typing name --</form:option>
                    <form:options items="${organizationsList}" itemLabel="organization" itemValue="org_id" /></form:select>
            </spring:bind>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="addOrgButton" value="Add" />
    <br>
</form:form>
```

This is a screenshot of the page with relevent elements after clicking "Add."  As you can see there are elements on the page but they are invisible.  I should have two "Organization" drop down lists.
[image: my page after clicking "Add"]

Comment: Smells like css stacked rules matter .. Any url ?

Comment: are they even valid elements?  This is getting parsed by the browser not the server so how would the browser understand `<spring:message code="label.org_id" />` and your other elements - view your other organization drop down and see if it looks the same as the one you just created

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ <spring:message code="label.org_id" /> is the same element which displays "Organization" before the first drop down list.

Comment: It's on the jsp page - which runs on the server side though and gets parsed there into valid HTML - your browser doesn't understand that

Comment: @f00bar, I've tried it without any CSS at all.  firebug confirms that there is no styling involved.

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ, I see what you're saying.  How would I get around this?

Comment: so you just want to make a copy of the dropdown? or are the options different?

Comment: Options would be the same...maybe I could code several of these into the page as invisible and make them visible when "add" is clicked... but I didn't want to limit how many could be added

Comment: there's always [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) which allows you to make a copy of an element - then you just have to increment that number

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ, Awesome!  I found someone else's thread where they have a clone() and regular expression matcher to increment.  Its all making sense now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very helpful article here... [jquery clone form fields and increment id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018132/jquery-clone-form-fields-and-increment-id)

So the answer is to use clone() and use a regular expression to increment your index. Details and an example are given at above link. Appending a Spring form element will not work as the append is happening browser side and spring form elements are compiled server side. Browsers know nothing of Spring elements.