# Changing aria-control attribute value in Cloned fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've altered the code given by Milan Jaric from this question [Jquery Clone Form Fields and increment ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018132/jquery-clone-form-fields-and-increment-id) but I'm coming across an issue where I'm trying to clone a Bootstrap collapse. I can't see to figure out how to alter the attribute 'aria-control' value.

Here's [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3hbjfkuh/) of what I currently have. the ID and HREF work fine by themselves, but the moment I try to change the 'aria-control' value, all of the ids and hrefs in the bootstrap collapse do not change from the default values.  Any ideas?

**JS Script**

```
var regex = /^(.*)(\d)+$/i;
var cloneIndex = $(".clonedBox").length;

function clone() {
    $(this).parents(".clonedBox").clone()
        .appendTo("div#accession_boxes")
        .attr("id", "clonedBox" + cloneIndex)
        .find("*")
        .each(function () {
            var id = this.id || "";
            var match = id.match(regex) || [];

            if (match.length == 3) {
                this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
                this.href = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
                this.attr("a[aria-controls]") = match[1] + cloneIndex;
            }
        })
        .on('click', '#btnAddBox', clone)
        .on('click', '#btnDelBox', remove);
    cloneIndex++;
}
function remove() {
    $(this).parents(".clonedBox").remove();
}
$("#btnAddBox").on("click", clone);

$("#btnDelBox").on("click", remove);
```

And yes, I know my remove buttons do not work, but it's not a priority right now.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to **lmgonzalves**, the JS Script now works. Below is the updated script. Thank you again for all of the help!

JS SCRIPT (UPDATED)

```
    var regex = /^(.*)(\d)+$/i;
var cloneIndex = $(".clonedBox").length;

function clone() {
    $(this).parents(".clonedBox").clone()
        .appendTo("div#accession_boxes")
        .attr("id", "clonedBox" + cloneIndex)
        .find("*")
        .each(function () {
            var id = this.id || "";
            var href = this.href || "";
            var aria = $(this).attr("aria-controls") || "";

            var matchID = id.match(regex) || [];
            var matchHref = href.match(regex) || [];
            var matchAria = aria.match(regex) || [];

            if (matchID.length == 3) {
                this.id = matchID[1] + (cloneIndex);
                this.href = matchHref[1] + (cloneIndex);
                this.aria = matchAria[1] + (cloneIndex);
            }
        })
        .on('click', '#btnAddBox', clone)
        .on('click', '#btnDelBox', remove);
    cloneIndex++;
}
function remove() {
    $(this).parents(".clonedBox").remove();
}
$("#btnAddBox").on("click", clone);

$("#btnDelBox").on("click", remove);
```

Comment: `this.attr("a[aria-controls]") = match[1] + cloneIndex;` does nothing, pass 2 args to set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set an attribute using [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) you need this syntax:

```
$(element).attr("name", value);
```

So in your code use:

```
$(this).attr("aria-controls", match[1] + cloneIndex);
```

Instead:

```
this.attr("a[aria-controls]") = match[1] + cloneIndex;
```

Note that also you need to "wrap" with `$()` the `this` to convert it to jQuery object and to allow use `attr()` and others jQuery functions.

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/3hbjfkuh/1/)